# Randomly missing nodes in html when scraping with GuzzleClient

Tags: php, parsing, guzzle, scrape

I'm dealing here with an issue on scrape because of the inconsistency of the child elements, that sometimes are present and other times missing.

Since I'm saving state referencing the `$values[]` array, what I found was that sometimes `$value[18]` is the email address, other times it can be the phone or fax.

The sample array of three iterations is as follows:

```
[0] => [
    [1] => Firm: The Firm One Name
    [2] => Firm:
    [3] => The Firm One Name
    [4] => Office: 5th Av. 18980, NY
    [5] => Office:
    [6] => 5th Av. 18980, NY
    [7] => City: New York 
    [8] => City:
    [9] => New York
    [10] => Country: USA
    [11] => Country:
    [12] => USA
    [13] => Tel: +123 4 567 890
    [14] => Tel:
    [15] => +123 4 567 890
    [16] => Email: person.one@example.com
    [17] => Email:
    [18] => person.one@example.com
],
[1] => [
    [1] => Firm: The Firm Two Name
    [2] => Firm:
    [3] => The Firm Two Name
    [4] => Office: 5th Av. 342680, NY
    [5] => Office:
    [6] => 5th Av. 342680, NY
    [7] => City: New York
    [8] => City:
    [9] => New York
    [10] => Country: USA
    [11] => Country:
    [12] => USA
    [13] => Tel: +123 4 567 890
    [14] => Tel:
    [15] => +123 4 567 890
    [16] => Fax: +123 4 567 891
    [17] => Fax:
    [18] => +123 4 567 891
    [19] => Email: person.two@example.com
    [20] => Email:
    [21] => person.two@example.com
],
    [2] => [[1] => Firm: The Firm Three Name
    [2] => Firm:
    [3] => The Firm Three Name
    [4] => Office: 5th Av. 89280, NY
    [5] => Office:
    [6] => 5th Av. 89280, NY
    [7] => Country: USA
    [8] => Country:
    [9] => USA
    [10] => Fax: +123 4 567 899
    [11] => Fax:
    [12] => +123 4 567 899
    [13] => Email: person.three@example.com
    [14] => Email:
    [15] => person.three@example.com
]
```

As it might be noticeable, when I iterate and save `$values[15]` of the last array, which is the email address, on the first `[0][15]` corresponds to a Tel. number.

My question is, **is there a simpler way than doing a 'crazy loop'** over the fields and always save the email as an email and not as a phone number?

I'm using `GuzzleClient()` along with `$node->filterXPath()` and/or `$node->filter()` depending on what I have to grab.

The html structure I'm working on is very short and simple as the example below, **sometimes there are nodes missing...**:

```
<div id="profiledtails">
<div class="abc-g">
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Firm:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">
            <a href="http://example.com/123456/" title="More information here" class="Item" abc-tracker="office" abc-tracking="true">Person One</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Office:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">
            <address>
                5th Av.<br>18980,<br>NY
            </address>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">City:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">New York</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Country:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">USA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Tel:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">+123 4 567 890</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Fax:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">+123 4 567 891</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Email:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">
            <a href="mailto:mperson.one@example.com">person.one@example.com</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking some rest and thinking freshly about the problem, I found the solution that gets the data sanitised as needed. After all it's just a matter of filtering the results and get the correct values in the correct place in the array.
Here's what I make and works for any case (when adapted to ones needs):

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//*[@id="profiledetails"]/div')->each(function($node) use ($data, $start, $i) {

    // get the values
    foreach($node->filter('div') as $k => $v) {
        $values[] = trim($v->nodeValue);
    }

    // sanitise the data
    $sanitised = [];
    foreach($values as $k => $v) {
        trim($v); // trim to make sure there's no spaces
        if($v == 'Firm:') {
            $sanitised['firm_name'] = $values[$k + 1]; // Note: the +1 is to get the next node where the value is set
        }
        if($v == 'Office:') {
            $sanitised['address'] = $values[$k + 1];
        }
        if($v == 'City:') {
            $sanitised['city'] = $values[$k + 1];
        }
        if($v == 'Country:') {
            $sanitised['country'] = $values[$k + 1];
        }
        if($v == 'Tel:') {
            $sanitised['phone'] = $values[$k + 1];
        }
        if($v == 'Fax:') {
            $sanitised['fax'] = $values[$k + 1];
        }
        if($v == 'Email:') {
            $sanitised['email'] = $values[$k + 1];
        }
    }

    $data['firm_name'] = !empty($sanitized['firm_name']) ? $sanitized['firm_name'] : null;
    $data['address'] = !empty($sanitized['address']) ? nl2br($sanitized['address']) : null;
    $data['city'] = !empty($sanitized['city']) ? $sanitized['city'] : null;
    $data['country'] = !empty($sanitized['country']) ? $sanitized['country'] : null;
    $data['phone'] = !empty($sanitized['phone']) ? $sanitized['phone'] : null;
    $data['fax'] = !empty($sanitized['fax']) ? $sanitized['fax'] : null;
    $data['email'] = !empty($sanitized['email']) ? $sanitized['email'] : null;

    // Save the data    
    ProfileModel::where('id', $i)->update($data);
    // just a console log to know where we are in case it fails on timeout
    echo "Done for profile id " . $i . PHP_EOL;    
});
```

The result will always, for each iteration, be a correct array even when empty or missing nodes are found. It looks like this:

```
[ 
    ['firm_name'] = 'Firm Name One';
    ['address'] = '5th Av.<br>18980,<br>NY';
    ['city'] = 'New Yok';
    ['country'] = 'USA';
    ['phone'] = '+123 4 567 890';
    ['fax'] = null;
    ['email'] = 'person.one@example.com';
]
```

And now every single row on the DB gets the data (or `NULL` ) in the right columns.

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with the same situation before and the only solution for this situation is **Regular Expression** because Html elements changes every time and you can't keep track on values until you use regex, Here is your fix

```
$re = '/        <div class="abc-u first">Email:<\/div>
        <div class="abc-u">
            <a href="mailto:mperson.one@example.com">(.*)<\/a>/';
$str = '<div id="profiledtails">
<div class="abc-g">
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Firm:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">
            <a href="http://example.com/123456/" title="More information here" class="Item" abc-tracker="office" abc-tracking="true">Person One</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Office:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">
            <address>
                5th Av.<br>18980,<br>NY
            </address>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">City:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">New York</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Country:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">USA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Tel:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">+123 4 567 890</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Fax:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">+123 4 567 891</div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc-gf">
        <div class="abc-u first">Email:</div>
        <div class="abc-u">
            <a href="mailto:mperson.one@example.com">person.one@example.com</a></div>
    </div>
</div>';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

In the same way you have to prepare regex for other values and you are ready to go, the code above looks messy but you can remove spaces from string and also from regex to make it clean.

Comment: Thanks Faraz for your help but although valid it doesn't fit my requirements. I have found a solution for the problem and this is what happens when you take some time to rest :) I'll post here the solution in a reply. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done by regular expression, I dont have much exposure with PHP, but for regular expression:

you can use following command for key:

```
class="abc-u first">(.*):
```

& for value:

```
class="abc-u">(.*?)</
```

Comment: Thanks Chhirag for your help but although valid it doesn't fit my requirements. I have found a solution for the problem and this is what happens when you take some time to rest :) I'll post here the solution in a reply. Thank you again.